# pointerId in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

js script

```
var count = false;
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", (more) => {
    moreOp = more.target.id
    console.log(moreOp)
});
```

html code

```
<div id="1">
     <label id="2"/>
     <input id="3"/>
</div>
```

out in console

> 2 //pointerId:1
> 3 //pointerId:2

how i can in a variable be given id element of pointer id 1 element ?

Answer (score 0):

use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

```js
document
  .getElementById("1")
  .addEventListener("click", event =>
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log('You clicked on the element with id =', event.target.id )
  console.log('the event listener belongs to the element with id =', event.currentTarget.id )
  })
```

```css
div[id="1"]  { background-color:yellow }
label[id="2"]  { background-color:pink }
```

```html
<div id="1">
  <label id="2" > label 2 </label>
  <input id="3" placeholder="input element..."/>
</div>
```

Comment: out in console is : 2 and 3 you can test it without clear console i need only to id of element pointer id of 1

Comment: @AriYa  it's in the code: you should use `event.currentTarget.id` instead of `event.target.id`  there is a link to the mdn documentation too

Comment: i used from this but in console i received : 1 and 1

Comment: @AriYa it's depending where you click, if you put your click in space outside elements 2 or 3 ( but inside the div id=1 area wich is yellow ) it give you 1 and 1